# Combine multiple text files in Vim

Tags: vim

I have a fairly simple question that I can't find an answer to, and can't seem to make work for me.

I need to append multiple text files (all within the same directory) within Vim. The reason I need to do it within Vim is that I'm running windows and don't have access to *nix utilities.

All the files have a pattern in their name (`ex1.sql`, `ex2.sql`, `ex3.sql`).

All I need to do is grad the text from them (in the order they are in the directory), and append them into a new blank file.

I've made the argument list

```
:args ex*.sql
```

And want to perform a command on all the args into the `a` register.

```
:argdo gg"AyG
```

It says that the lines were copied from each of the files.

When I go to paste the register into a new file, however, nothing prints.

```
:"ap
```

So I check the register:

```
:reg
```

the `a` register is filled with gibberish (`^]Jyecw?`).

Is there a better way of going about this? Why is it saying that it's copying into a register, but is in fact putting in a bunch of strange characters?

Comment: Check out this plugin which should do what you need: http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2789

Comment: Did you mean to put the colon in there in front of `"ap`?

Comment: A side note, on Windows you can combine files with the DOS copy command. copy ex*.sql excombined.sql

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`argdo` executes an `ex-mode` command in each file of the argument list. What you want to do with `gg"AyG` is execute a `normal` command. Try:

```
:argdo normal gg"AyG
```

Comment: Vimgolf time: `:argdo %y A`

Comment: Use `:normal!` to avoid clashes with mapping.

Comment: Do not forget to clear the register beforehand using `qaq` or `:let @a=''`.

Comment: @ib I'm not sure what you mean by "clashes with mapping". Also, thanks for including the bit on clearing the register. I was looking for how to do that as well.

Comment: I was very close, I was just careless when it came to the paste register syntax (I was including the semicolon).

Comment: @svh160 There is no preferred method. But I assume many like to use unix's `cat` or windows `copy` command (e.g. `copy mar89.rpt + apr89.rpt + may89.rpt report`). As for using vim it is probably up to the individual, whatever feels right. I personally like the shorter method b/c it uses pure ex commands which tend to be quicker. Of course there is a chance of blowing past your register size. Then it may be best to use `:argdo w >> destination.txt`